# Get Product List with more details in Magento2 API

Tags: json, api, magento2

I am working on a native application and need to get the list of product based on category.

Like when user clicks on a category I have to show list of products inside that category.

I tried a service but its only giving three field in return

```
    http://www.dexample.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories/1680/products
```

response

```
{
    "sku": "FB-Bridgewater",
    "position": 1,
    "category_id": "1680"
}
```

I need more information like name, image,  price and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the search API to fetch the more information of the Product.

This API will get you the products with details:

```
http://www.dexample.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1680&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

The Generic Search API of Magento2 is

```
searchCriteria[filter_groups][<index>][filters][<index>][field]=<field_name>
searchCriteria[filter_groups][<index>][filters][<index>][value]=<search_value>
searchCriteria[filter_groups][<index>][filters][<index>][condition_type]=<operator>
```

where:

`field` is an attribute name.

`value` specifies the value to search for.

`condition_type` specifies condition[ex: eq , finset, like, from, to]

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I get the list of product reviews and if I have multiple options in the product like color and one of its option is chargeable for e.g. red colour change extra $5 then which API to call and change the product of product

Comment: You can get the details of specific product by sku for ex:http://localhost/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products/sku

Comment: yes but I am not getting Review Details in that API

Comment: Currently there is no api provided for reviews, https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Feature-Requests-and/rest-api-are-not-available-for-wish-list-review-and-rating/idi-p/47173

Comment: Then can I show the product reviews in the Mobile Application

Comment: Thanks @Sudarshan